# Association's Key[key] extraction different in V10.1/V10.2

Tags: associations, language-design

V10.1:

```
<|a -> 1|>[Key @ a]
(* Missing["KeyAbsent", Key[a]]*)
```

V10.0:

```
<|a -> 1|>[Key @ a]
(* 1 *)
```

Bug or Design Change?

**Update:**
This bug/design change remains in 10.2.

Even though my conclusions in a separate answer differ from the accepted @Szabolcs answer (not to mention the other answers and WRI's developers!) the approach of seeing the issue in a broader context is useful for clarifying the operation of *any* key extraction implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only the designer could say if this is a bug or a bugfix. But, like others, I also consider this change an improvement.  What follows is just personal opinion on why, backed up by observations.

How would you design associations if your goal was to allow any expression to be a key (useful as shown by `GroupBy`, `Counts`, etc.) and also keep associations user friendly?

As I see, the primary function of `Key` is to disambiguate between *numerical indices* and *keys that can be any expression* in functions that take both.

We have two categories of functions.  One that can take either numerical indices or keys, such as:

- `Part`, `Extract`, `ReplacePart`, etc.

And another one that takes only keys, such as

- `<| ... |>[...]`, `KeyExistQ`, `KeyTake`, `Lookup`, etc.

Based on 10.1 behaviour, this appears to be the general behaviour:

- Functions that can take numerical arguments as well require key names to be wrapped by `Key`.  An exception is strings, which are automatically treated as if they were already wrapped in `Key`.  Any other expression is disallowed.
- Functions that can only take keys, interpret the key name literally.

These rules will make key handling convenient and unambiguous:

```
asc = <|a -> 1, 1 -> 2, Key[1] -> 3, "z" -> 4, Key["z"] -> 5,
    Key["w"] -> 6|>;

asc[[a]]

During evaluation of Part::pkspec1: The expression a cannot be used as a part specification. >>
(* <|a -> 1, 1 -> 2, Key[1] -> 3, "z" -> 4, Key["z"] -> 5, 
  Key["w"] -> 6|>[[a]] *)

asc[[Key[a]]]
(* 1 *)

asc[[1]]
(* 1 *)

asc[[Key[1]]]
(* 2 *)

asc[["z"]] (* automatically treated as Key["z"] *)
(* 4 *)

asc[[Key["z"]]]
(* 4 *)

asc[["w"]]
(* Missing["KeyAbsent", "w"] *)

asc[[Key@Key["z"]]]
(* 5 *)

asc[a]
(* 1 *)

asc[1]
(* 2 *)

asc[Key[1]]
(* 3 *)

asc["z"]
(* 4 *)

asc[Key["z"]]
(* 5 *)

asc[Key@Key["z"]]
(* Missing["KeyAbsent", Key[Key["z"]]] *)
```

Allowing both wrapped (`Key[...]`) and unwrapped names in situations where only key names are expected would lead to ambiguities.  What would `asc[Key["z"]]` refer to?  The key `"z"` or the key `Key["z"]`?  As Mr. Wizard points it out, how could we even test reliably if a key exists or not?

You noticed that `Lookup` does indeed accept both wrapped and unwrapped keys, and this leads to some strange behaviour.  Both `Lookup[<|"z" -> 1|>, Key["z"], default]` and `Lookup[<|"z" -> 1|>, "z", default]` give `1` even though `Key["z"] =!= "z"`.  This is what I'd consider a bug instead of wrapped forms not working where only names are expected.

You would be of course right if you said that using key names which themselves include `Key` is not a very good idea anyway, but if the language can be designed to avoid ambiguities, I think it is really better to do so.

Comment: < What would `asc[Key["z"]]` refer to? The key `"z"` or the key `Key["z"]`?

Why not both as this is clearly the user's intent?

<<Both `Lookup[<|"z" -> 1|>`, `Key["z"], default]` and `Lookup[<|"z" -> 1|>, "z", default]` give `1` even though `Key["z"] =!= "z"`. This is what I'd consider a bug ...

Both `<|"a" -> 1|>[[Key@"a"]]` and `<|"a" -> 1|>[["a"]]`  give `1` even though `Key@"a" =!= "a"`. This is *not* what I'd consider a bug  ...

Comment: The second seems less of a bug probably due to familiarilty but also on the back of required disambiguation and not penalizing the user applying abundant caution.  Again, IMO, user intent is ... er ... key.


... Actually perhaps a more compelling reason why I think this should be a considered a bug is that this is not (just) a case of extending a user's expectation to cases where it is not strictly needed -  sometimes it is needed and indeed for another type of disambiguation - that of a function operator in queries - e.g. ...

Comment: `data=Dataset[{<|a->1|>}];`
`data[All,Key@a]`
`data[All,a]`
`data[All,1]`
`data[All,Key[1]]` I suppose you could argue that you can differentiate between `Dataset` and an `Association` but I think this detracts from clarity/consistency. All of which just goes to show, language design is hard! (and underestimated).

Comment: Here's another example involving pure functions: `{#a, #"a", #[Key@a], #[Key@"a"]}&@<|a -> 1, "a" -> 2|>` I think most users would expect the first element to return `1` instead of the currently returned `2` (I think this is probably another bug) but having a `Key` wrapper can put any doubts to bed as per the last two, now failing extractions. This is therefore not mere disambiguation but scope since as far as I can tell, currently there is *no* way to "purely" extract `a` .

Answer (score 5):

**Summary: Yes it is a "bug" and it also suggests changing `[]`, `#&` and `KeyTake`'s key extracting semantics:**

**Background: A Disambiguating Imperative Emerges:**

While related to language design, subtlities such as these do impact de-bugging, the selection of apt data structures and internal consistency as a WL Data Science code bases mature. The issue here seems to be one of meta-language and disambiguation with a certain incoherency present with the current semantics.

The need for an initial disambiguation involved separating the specification of a part by (traditional) position and by (recently introduced) name. So while a construction like `assoc[[1]]` traditionally defines the first part of `assoc`, once keys are allowed to include arbitrary expressions, a potential conflict arises since `assoc[[1]]` can potentially also refer to the value of key, `1`. The implemented disambiguation is to wrap `Key` over expressions intended to be interpreted as keys with no wrapping required for strings since their key status is implicit.

At first pass, `assoc[Key[a]]` doesn't seem subject to such a disambiguating imperative. The functional `assoc[a]` key extraction has no indexing precedent so arguments can apparently always be assumed to be literal keys. Hence, the usage `assoc[Key[a]]` appears redundant and presumably underpins the post V10.1 design decision to interpret it as the literal key, `Key[a]`, (similar to all other literal key interpretations).  Consequently, even with an `Association` containing the key, `a`, an error message is produced, with the "positive" affect of guiding users to the simpler usage `assoc[a]` (that is, without the "esoteric" `Key[a]` key already existing in the `Association` in which case its value would be returned instead).

**A Design Oversight**

I think this is a design oversight for the following reason:

First note (by the same reasoning) the following "redundancy":

```
{assoc[["a"]], assoc[[Key["a"]]]}
```

> {1, 1}

That the second, `assoc[[Key["a"]]]`, also returns `1` might seem like a polite nicety by way of ensuring users are not unduly penalized for displaying abundant caution, but it is actually more fundamental. One of the most powerful features IMO of the new Data Science functionality is the query operators and in particular, their composability (part of underpinning the development of operator forms) including the flexibility of its constituent operators. This means that, in general, a construct housing any key query knows not from whence it came.

So, for example, while the redundancy of `assoc[[Key["a"]]]` is clear enough, in general, another key, say `Key[b]`, may well emerge from a prior collection of keys and code, in particular, as part of disambiguating an earlier `[[Key[b]]]` construction. If this key, as part of a chain of query compositions, subsequently appears as say `assocA[Key[b]]`, its intended interpretation is clearly to, within `assocA`, find the value of the key, `b`. Hence this construct had better start indexing the key, `b` instead of heading off on a wild goose chase indexing the more "esoteric" key, `Key[b]` - which is what takes place in the current implementation (note that `Query[Key[b]]@assocA` works as expected and the link with the [] notation as part of `Dataset` queries).

This can be clarified by the following (where the "ambiguity concerns" raised by Mr. Wizard and Szabolcs in their answers are also addressed).

**Unification through consistent *Key-Descending Indexing***

[image]

From this collection, it can be observed that `Key[x]`'s semantics differ depending on its housing construct: for `[[]]` and `Lookup` it means the key, `x`; conversely, for `[]` and `KeyTake`, it means the key, `Key[x]`. I'll label the former interpretation, *descending-key indexing* and the latter, *literal-key indexing*. Hence the current situation is as follows:

- `[[ ]]` is a *key-descending, string-literal indexer*
- `Lookup` is a *key-descending, symbol-literal, string-literal indexer*
- `[]`, `#&`, `KeyTake`, are all *key-literal, symbol-literal, string-literal indexers*

What I claim is a much safer, more coherent design is instead:

- `[[ ]]` is a *key-descending, string-literal indexer*
- `[]`, `#&`, `KeyTake` & `Lookup`, are all *key-descending, symbol-literal, string-literal indexers*

Hence the design change entails ensuring `[]`, `#&` and `KeyTake` all become *key-descending indexers*.

In the previous collection shown in the image, this would mean resolving the current "bugs" to instead produce the following outputs

```
{assoc[Key[a]], #[Key[a]]&@assoc, KeyTake[assoc, Key[a]]}
```

> `{3, 3, <|a -> 3|>}`

instead of the current `{4, 4, <|a -> 4|>}` (n.b, and to also become consistent with `Query[Key[a]]@assoc`)

Now let me adress Mr. Wizard and Szabolcs reasonable points (that also clarified my thinking) to show that in fact this design change is not ambiguous nor does it represent a loss of scope (unlike the current post-10.1 change which for the above reasons *is* ambiguous). While my sense is that the current *key-literal indexing* was originally motivated more by the apparent *lack* of a disambiguation imperative, they suggest that it may instead relate to *another* potential disambiguation imperative - that of distinguishing those cases where `Key[a]` is in fact a key (and  hence the aforementioned "wild good chase" is nothing of the sort).

Firstly, I think this is unlikely to be the case as it doesn't seem to me to be a natural thing to want to do - include `Key[a]->1` as part of an `Association`? If for whatever reason it is implemented however, then consistent, *key-descending indexing* handles it simply and unambiguously - just use `Key[Key[a]]`. Sure, to those crazy `Key[a]->1` key constructors, this would seem more unwieldy but equally, it would be bizarre to accommodate a weird construction at the expense of the entire coherency of WL's key-extracting mechanism (further, if `Key[a]->1` really was a widespread desired element of an `Association` then it could always be considered as `a->1` for key extraction purposes).

**Coherency, Pedagogy and Backward Compatibility Advantages**

Finally, any design change needs to incorporate backward compatability but the nice thing about this change is that the main effect would simply be to ensure that previous error messages no longer appear from users either applying "abundant caution" or else following the same pattern/expectations inculcated from previous *descending-key indexing*. The only change in terms of non-error-message output would be the esoteric usage just described which I suspect would be non-existent at any rate).

Most important of all however, this change would mean that potential inconsistencies in future `Key[a]` interpretations can no longer occur something that IMO has only not yet bitten due to both shy users and WL's still maturing process in weighty data science applications.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to merely *guess* that it is an intentional change as:

1. there exist other ways to extract the same element, e.g.:

   ```
   <|a -> 1|>[[Key[a]]]

   Key[a] @ <|a -> 1|>
   ```
2. it is more general to allow verbatim `Key` within keys

   ```
   KeyExistsQ[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]        (* false *)

   KeyExistsQ[<|Key[a] -> 1|>, Key[a]]   (* true *)
   ```

Comment: Perhaps but I'm going to plump for a bug. 1. I think is overridden by what users might expect and redundancy can also be a strength 2. Can perhaps be true in both cases while it seems more natural to use `Key` as an argument rather than using to wrap a key already in a key position. `Key` is also used to disambiguate in `Part` (between a `Key` and a `Position`) and while this disambiguation seems less important in an `Apply`, where it is also not needed the redundancy is also allowed e.g. `Lookup[<|a -> 1|>, Key@a]` but OTOH -  `KeyTake[<|a -> 1|>, Key@a]`? Anyway, seems inconsistent.

Comment: @Ronald I probably need to give this more thought.  My initial comment, since deleted, was "I have no idea" and that is perhaps where I should have stopped.

Comment: @RonaldMonson Good point about `Lookup`.  I'd rather call Lookup's behaviour a bug here ...  what if we have `asc = <|Key[1] -> 2, 1 -> 3|>`?

Answer (score 3):

In V10.1

```
a = 42;
<|a -> 1|>[a]
```

gives

> ```
> 1
> ```

I look at this as a fix for a bug or design flaw that made the use of symbol keys awkward in V10.0. The loss of the `<|a -> 1|>[Key @ a]` is a small price to pay for what we have gained.

Comment: I think I agree with this change  re the non-evaluation (although questioning somewhat the point of symbols as keys? I suppose evaluation can be enforced with `With` injections) as user-intent is likely to more commonly not want such evaluation. But I'm not sure this price needs to be paid as can't you have both?

Comment: Note that the rule inside the association here evaluates, as does the `a` in the "argument" of the association. `a = 42; assoc = <|a -> 2|>; assoc[a] == assoc[42]` gives `True`. Compare with `assoc2 = <|Unevaluated[a -> 3]|> ; 
assoc2[[Unevaluated@Key@a]] =!= assoc2[a]`